# Docusign | Developer Sandbox | When should signers have a docusign account?

Tags: docusignapi, digital-signature

I've a use-case to integrate e-signature with an existing application of some confidential customer.

Initial question that came into my mind was: "Does signer need to have docusign account or not ?"
I've found the answer of the above question in "Login Requirements" section of this article:
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-security-settings

As per above answer, it depends on the sender whether s/he wants signer to have docusign account or not.
But my question is "**Why and in Which case a sender would like to have signer's docusign account and In which case it would be fine without signer's account ?**"

Need help regarding the use-cases, i.e when an account is needed and when not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Re: Need help regarding the use-cases, i.e when an account is needed and when not.

With DocuSign, a signer very rarely needs a DocuSign account nor has any charge for a signer.

Senders always need an account on DocuSign.

Signers don't need an account when:

- The signing request is sent to them via email
- nor when the signing ceremony is presented within the flow of a website (embedded signing)

The only time that I can think of where the signer must have an account is when the sender wants DocuSign to implement [Part 11](https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/part-11-electronic-records-electronic-signatures-scope-and-application) privacy rules for their account. In this case, the signer must authenticate themselves and log into a DocuSign account before signing.